# Best software to write C++ programs

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a program to write c++ language. I heard that C++ have cpp codes and header codes as well as implementing cppunit test. I would like a program that can perform all that.

If possible, include the instructions on how to install the software.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: on what OS should it run, what features do you need, how much you'd be willing to invest if it comes to paid software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Visual C++**, well that is the most trending software used nowdays, but I would prefer **Eclipse for C/C++**, as it provides you all the required syntax and added functionality.

Comment: Eclipse is the industry standard